# In Lord Byron's "Don Juan," what was the lead character "half-smother'd" by?

Tags: meaning, literature

This would be the character's first adventure. Julia, a married woman, became his mistress. Her husband, Don Alfonso, was told that she was cheating on him and ran into the bedroom, accompanied by servants, in order to surprise her and her lover.

Anticipating this, Julia asked her maid to lie in bed with her, while Don Juan squeezed in between them and was hidden completely by the sheets.

Don Alfonso and the servants searched the entire room, looked under the bed, and failed to find Julia's lover. Julia, pretending to be insulted, shouted at her husband who, realizing he was misled, hung his head in shame and left.

No sooner did the maid bolt the bedroom's door than Don Juan sprang from the bed "half-smother'd."

Now, pay attention:

> He had been hid—I don’t pretend to say
> How, nor can I indeed describe the where—
> Young, slender, and pack’d easily, he lay,
> No doubt, in little compass, round or square;
> But pity him I neither must nor may
> His **suffocation** by that pretty pair;
> ’Twere better, sure, to die so, than be shut
> With maudlin Clarence in his Malmsey butt.
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```
>
> Of his position I can give no notion:
> ’Tis written in the Hebrew Chronicle,
> How the physicians, leaving pill and potion,
> Prescribed, by way of blister, a young belle,
> When old King David’s blood grew dull in motion,
> And that the medicine answer’d very well;
> Perhaps ’twas in a different way applied,
> For David lived, but Juan **nearly died**.

Now: what exactly did he nearly die *of*?

Were they squashing him?

Or was it the smell?

Or just the lack of air?

What is Byron getting at here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Literature SE as it's about interpreting deliberately suggestive literature and biblical knowledge, and doesn't raise any issues about the English language.

Comment: I agree that this question is better on Literature SE, but Juan nearly died of being stabbed, or some other violence, which Don Alfonso would have inflicted on him if he had been discovered.